# In C++ class with copy & move ctor and copy assignment: no need for move assignment?

Tags: c++11

If I have a C++ class with copy and move constructors and copy assignment like so:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int A[];

    // custom ctor
    Foo(size_t N) {
        A = new A[N];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) A[i] = i * i;
    }

    // copy ctor
    Foo(Foo& other) {
        size_t N = sizeof(other.A) / sizeof(int);
        A = new A[N];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) A[i] = other.A[i];
    }

    // move ctor
    Foo(Foo&& other) {
        A = other.A;
        other.A = nullptr;
    }

    // copy assignment AND move assignment?
    Foo& operator=(Foo other) {
        std::swap(this.A, other.A);
        return *this;
    }

    // default dtor
    ~Foo() {
        delete[] A;
    }
```

Can I in this case simply avoid defining a move assignment operator and assume that still move assignment is taking place when possible?
My reasoning behind that is: the copy assignment operator has to construct the `Foo` object defined as parameter. Now it can choose between the copy ctor and the move ctor as both are available. Thus if given an `rvalue` it should choose the move ctor and if given an `lvalue` it should choose the copy ctor. Is this correct?

Also: will this implementation work regarding the `sizeof` calculation of the array? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommendation: Use `std::vector`

Problem: `int A[];` is a flexible array member, which gets its storage from extra memory adjacent to the main object.  You can't do `A = new int[N];` nor `sizeof (A)`.

Fix: You can use `int* A;` and keep track of the size yourself, because `sizeof` a pointer isn't related to the size of the array it points to.

Better: `std::vector<int>` remembers its size and implements destructor, move, and copy operations so you don't have to.

---

Regarding the question about implementing assignment using pass-by-value: Yes, that's legal, it's even an idiom: "copy-and-swap".  However, it will cause an unnecessary extra move in the move assignment case, so you may want to implement that directly.  Or not, since two moves should barely cost more than the required one.

If you use `std::vector` to store your data, the compiler-generated copy and move operations will do the right thing automatically.

Comment: Ok for the part regarding the array! Thanks!
But for the part regarding `move`: my point is, that this is not just `copy-and-swap`, but instead `move-and-swap`. My point being that this is by far not as expensive as copy assignment and nearly as fast as a normal `move` assignment. As much so that I even question what benefit a `move` assignment operator here would give.
_If_ my whole reasoning above is correct.

Comment: @BM: Yes, it does two move operations, zero copies, when move assignment is needed.  Pass-by-value certainly does use the move constructor where possible.

Comment: so my reasoning in the end is correct that in such cases defining an explicit `move` assignment gives mostly no real benefit? Could you point that out in your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always don't define the move ctor and assignment operators. All you will lose is opportunity of performance gains. So no, no *need* for move assignment.

In your case, this example `Foo f = Foo(); f = Foo()` you're using the normal assignment operator, where you could be doing a `move`. You will do that in two moves instead plus the `swap`.

<s>About you `sizeof` question, it wont work. `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer type, which is constant</s>**EDIT:** except for VLA, where it performs a run-time check, so it is correct.

Comment: That's initialization, and doesn't use *any* assignment operator at all.

Comment: What pointer type?  `A` is a flexible array member, not a pointer.

Comment: @VillasV: imho this answer completely ignores my whole reasoning above. My point is that a `move` (actually two moves) is what happens if you do an assignment.

Comment: "a move" instead of "two moves", perhaps would have been better said

Comment: It's not a VLA either.

Comment: @BenVoigt Isn't its size defined at run-time? I thought this was enough to call it as VLA.

Comment: @VillasV: No, its size really isn't defined.  It just walks over adjacent memory (due to pointer arithmetic), so someone has to dynamically allocate extra memory for the structure itself, and there's no language syntax for doing so.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: TIL. I'd make another question just to accept that as an answer. In fact I think I'll do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt that article and another question on SO points out that there's no flexible array member on C++. Was it added on C++11 or 14?

Comment: @VillasV: Nope, neither flexible array members nor VLAs are valid in any version of the C++ standard.